# Differentiate page opening depending on the action taken

Tags: php

I'm having troubles with the code below. Instead of messages I would like it to open one of these two pages depending on the action taken by the user. I think I should use something else there than echo, but I'm not too familiar with PHP coding. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
$check = $_POST['template']; 
  if ($check==false)
{
   echo 'thankyou.php';
}
   else
{

   echo 'error.php'; 
                    mail($to, $subject, $body);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect them to the page use header("Location: thankyou.php"). If you want to show the pages use include "thankyou.php";